# Is there is a way to set up google cloud logging for quarkus?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logback, quarkus, google-cloud-logging, jboss-logging

The only thing stopping me from using quarkus on my projects is the lack of google cloud logging support.

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java

Because google cloud logging use Logback appender for cloud logging, and quarkus use JBoss Logging.

Is there is a way to fix that? Or maybe some workaround?

Thank you

Comment: Apparently Cloud Logging support can also be achieved by using a `java.util.logging` handler. Quarkus uses JBoss LogManager as the logging backend, which is an extension of JUL, so using the JUL handler (`com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler`) might work.

Comment: @Ladicek Thank you, I will try to make this work. I was hoping that there is more straightforward approach, or out of the box way, I will update this thread if it works

Comment: You may need an extension to use a different log handler. For Google Cloud related extension their developement is inside this repo https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-google-cloud-services you can open a feature request or even send a PR ;)
I'm the maintainer of this extension pack.

Comment: @Ladicek thank you for your suggestion, but looks like it is not possible right now, https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6133

Answer (score 1):

**StackDriver will make the log lines appear in Google Cloud Logging.**

Quarkus supports several logging APIs: JUL (java.util.logging), JBoss Logging, [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) and Apache Commons Logging.

**java.util.logging configuration (JUL):**

[Logging handlers](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java#javautillogging_configuration) can be added programmatically or by using a configuration file. The path to the configuration file must be provided to your application as a system property: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/logging.properties
You can use the JUL handler com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler

**JBoss Logging:**

Internally Quarkus uses JBoss Logging; you can also use it inside your application so that no other dependencies should be added for your logs.

Note : If you use JBoss Logging but one of your libraries uses a different logging API, you may need to configure a Logging adapter.

**SLF4J :**

Using the Logback appender, you can use Cloud Logging with the SLF4J logging facade.

Once you have configured Logback to use the Cloud Logging Logback appender, you can now redirect logs using the SLF4J logging API. The [snippet](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java#example) shows how to log using the SLF4J facade within your application.

Refer this [guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging-guide) for more information on Quarkus about configuring logs